# Check whether user is logged in or not and require different pages depending on that

Tags: php, sql

I have a webpage that has sensitive information, that I do not want logged out users to access, and that's why I need to include different menus depending on whether the user is logged in or not. This is the code I have right now.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || isset($_SESSION['user'])=="")
{
    require('menu.php');
}
if else(isset($_SESSION['user']) || isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    require('homemenu.php');
}
```

But it doesn't show any of the menus no matter how I proceed with it.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `if else` or `elseif`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have initiated the session by adding `session_start()` at top of your page on both login page (during registering session and on current page) and then use this shortened version of your conditions:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) AND $_SESSION['user'] != '') {
    require ('homemenu.php');
} else {
    require ('menu.php');
}
```

Comment: I did have `session_start()` at the beginning, but the problem was the if statement. Why did this work, and not one I wrote?

Comment: Check on 5th line of your code. You need to use simply `else` and remove the condition.

Comment: Okay, but why does that make the code error? Because I should be able to have certain conditions, making sure that the user is either logged in, not logged in or an error should appear. I just don't understand why an `if else` statement does not work in this case.

Comment: Waaaait a minute... Is `if else`, `elseif` in php? I can't believe I've been so wrong this whole time! :D

Comment: You are using `if else` that's invalid. Change it with `else if`. It should work then. Both `else if` and `elseif` are valid but `if else` is not

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user'] == "" )
{
   require('menu.php');
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user'] != "" )
{
   require('homemenu.php');
}
```

Try this:

Comment: Did not work, unfortunately. The menu does not show up in any of the cases.

Comment: add `session_start()` at top of the file.